# Which answer is correct for this product rule based probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question reads like this:

> A bag contains 5 black and 3 red balls. A ball is taken out of the bag and is not returned to it. If this process is repeated three times, then what is the probability of drawing a black ball in the next draw?

**Solution 1**

I think the three balls can be drawn in 4 ways

- All the three balls are black = 5/8 .4/7 .3/6 then the probability of next black ball can be drawn is 2/5.
- 2 black and 1 red = 5/8 . 4/7 . 3/6 then the probability of next black ball can be drawn is 3/5.
- 1 black and 2 red = 5/8 . 3/7 . 2/6 then the probability of next black ball can be drawn is 4/5.
- All red = 3/8 . 2/7 . 1/6 then the probability of next black ball can be drawn is 1.

And probability of each way is 1/4.
Hence desired probability $=\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{3}{5}+\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{4}{5}+\frac{1}{4}\times1=\frac{7}{10} = 0.7$

**Solution 2**

Probability of 4th ball being black when

- All first first 3 draws are black balls $=\frac{5}{8}\times\frac{4}{7}\times\frac{3}{6}\times\frac{2}{5}=\frac{120}{1680}$
- First three draws contain all red balls $=\frac{3}{8}\times\frac{2}{7}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{5}{5}=\frac{30}{1680}$
- First three draws contain 2 red and 1 black ball $=\frac{3}{8}\times\frac{2}{7}\times\frac{5}{6}\times\frac{4}{5}\times 3=\frac{360}{1680}$
- First three draws contain 1 red and 2 black ball $=\frac{3}{8}\times\frac{5}{7}\times\frac{4}{6}\times\frac{3}{5}\times 3=\frac{540}{1680}$

Summing all above probabilities gives $=\frac{5}{8}=0.625$

I cant decide which one is correct. I feel the second one is just far more precise. Is it?

Comment: The second one is correct. In the first solution you are wrong in assigning to the four cases the same probability.

Comment: The answer is (after a while I think obviously, without calculation) $5/8$.

Comment: good its not just me who feels second approach is correct, however the [book](https://goo.gl/FlL6mv) I am referring solves it 7/10. Unfortunately solution key page is omitted in Google books. (But next question in the book asks probability of red ball in next draw and it solves in similar approach as solution 2.) Also few people online solves this question to 7/10. User @appi1107 on [this](http://goo.gl/rwScCa) page. And also on [this](http://goo.gl/hsC7z6) page. Also [this](http://goo.gl/PTtyix) site, though I feel this site simply copy pastes stuff from other sources. So am still confused.

Comment: Hi please tell why 1st one is incorrect. After thinking more I feel solution 1 is incorrect because it does not take into account the permutations of first three balls drawn that can result in each of the four cases. Is it the reason?

Comment: @Mahesha999  That is so.  The first solution calculates the probability of drawing two black balls then a red ball (in that order), but neglects to consider the possibility of drawing a red ball then two black balls, or of drawing a black ball, a red ball, then a black ball.  And so forth.

Comment: @GrahamKemp , is there a way to correct the first solution ? , I'm trying to figure out how to correct the first solution. Thank you :)

Comment: @PruthviRaj The second solution *is* the corrected way.  It takes account of the *3 arrangements* the first three balls can when one is a different colour, *and* the conditional probability of the fourth ball being black when given the count among the first three.

Comment: I will go with the solution 1 because the it includes the probability of the certain case to occur. We need to keep in mind that each case independent and the 1st solution counts it in. Although the second one is plausible it does not take into account the probability of the case itself which is relevant in this question because of the multiple trials !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things.   There are eight balls, and any one of which could be the fourth ball drawn with equal probability.   Five of these balls are black.   The probability that a black ball is drawn on the fourth draw is thus: $$5/8$$

---

This agrees with your second solution, which correctly considers that there are three ways to arrange two balls of one colour and one of another.

---

To see this in action, lets examine ways to draw balls from a bag of two black and two red balls, and count those where the third ball is black.  By my method we should expect $2/4$ of the possible arrangements to have a black ball drawn in third place. Let's see...

$$\begin{array}{cc}\bullet\bullet\circ\circ \\\bullet\circ\bullet\circ &\star\\ \bullet\circ\circ\bullet \\ \circ \bullet\bullet\circ & \star \\ \circ\bullet\circ\bullet \\ \circ\circ\bullet\bullet & \star\end{array}$$

Comment: your approach is quite surprising to me. *There are eight balls, and any one of which could be the fourth ball drawn with equal probability.   Five of these balls are black.   The probability that a black ball is drawn on the fourth draw is thus: 5/8*. However some black balls may have already taken out. Then there are not five black balls remained but lesser, in that case the probability will also be less. I could have said that the probability of (first) ball drawn without replacement is black is 5/8, but not the same about the fourth ball drawn. What I am missing?

Comment: @Mahesha999 Consider the case where you continue drawing the balls, one by one, from the bag and placing them in a line.  Sometimes more black balls will be drawn before it, and sometimes less, but of *all* of the (equally-)possible arrangements, five in eight will have a black ball drawn in the fourth place.  This is true for any particular place you choose, whether that place is first, second, third, fourth, all the way to last.

Comment: Is this approach supposed to be basic understanding that everyone should have? I mean I have practiced many problems on probability & my solution approach used to be like the one above, mostly driven by sample problems given in the book. Now seeing your seemingly simple approach, am just guessing what all types of problems are solvable with this approach? Am still disturbed why my [book](http://goo.gl/Q4iOJ9) (which is very popular for Indian business school exam prep) did not taught this & kept preaching more weird approaches. Now guessing what all it might have ill-taught to me.